# Adonis WebSockets Client - How to remove log statements in Nuxt.js

Tags: websocket, nuxt.js, adonis.js

Adonis js v4

I saw [here](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/websocket-client#_production_builds) that I should defining `NODE_ENV` via `Webpack DefinePlugin` or `rollup-plugin-replace`

`"@adonisjs/websocket-client": "^1.0.9"`

and I did that but nothing changed, when I build the nuxt project and then `nuxt start`

here is my nuxt.config.js

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
require('dotenv').config()
import webpack from 'webpack'

export default {
  ...

  build: {
   ...

   plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'NODE_ENV': 'production'
      })
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix to this is to add a `/index` when importing the package in a component, which is kinda weird but cant see any solution to this.

**It would look like this now:**
`import Ws from '@adonisjs/websocket-client/index'`

Comment: finally, after few months I can solve my problem.